# Loop with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm new to Reactive Programming and I have a big problem that I can't solve alone... I need to upload several video assets and in a orderly sequence but I do not know how to do it, I have an array of PHAssets and I'm trying to iterate thru each element and send it over the network
Here is my code so far with comments:

```
for item in items {
                    let fileName = item.media.localIdentifier

                    //Observable to generate local url to be used to save the compressed video
                    let compressedVideoOutputUrl = videoHelper.getDocumentsURL().appendingPathComponent(fileName)

                    //Observable to generate a thumbnail image for the video
                    let thumbnailObservable =  videoHelper.getBase64Thumbnail(myItem: item)

                    //Observable to request the video from the iPhone library
                    let videoObservable = videoHelper.requestVideo(myItem: item)

                        //Compress the video and save it on the previously generated local url
                        .flatMap { videoHelper.compressVideo(inputURL: $0, outputURL: compressedVideoOutputUrl) }
                    //Generate the thumbnail and share the video to send over the network
                    let send = videoObservable.flatMap { _ in thumbnailObservable }
                        .flatMap { api.uploadSharedFiles(item, filename: fileName, base64String: $0) }

                    //subscribe the observable
                    send.subscribe(onNext: { data in
                        print("- Done chain sharing Video -")
                    },
                                   onError: { error in
                                    print("Error sharing Video-> \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }).disposed(by: actionDisposeBag)

                }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to upload your items one by one in flatMap, then use enumeration

**EDIT:** enumeration is useful when you need to know the index of the element, otherwise just `flatMap` with one argument will do.

```
Observable.from(items)
    .enumerated()
    .flatMap() { index, item -> Observable<Item> in
        return uploadItem(item)
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent replies, I have a question, I have been reading about concatMap, will it be of any use in this case?

Comment: *.concatMap()* on the top level guarantees that order of the elements downstream is the same as order of *items*. See for yourself whether you need it.

Comment: how can we wait until all of them completed?

Answer (score 2):

Make observable from collection elements and *.flatMap()* them to your existing code -

```swift
Observable
  .from(items)
  .flatMap { (item) -> Any in
    // your code
      return send
  }
  .subscribe( /* your code */ )
  .disposed(by: actionDisposeBag)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to avoid risk of deletion